# queryRoots calls queryDocument first, not queryChildDocuments

Tags: android, storage-access-framework, documents-provider

I'm writing a wrapper for SAF wrapper for Dropbox since everyone (including Google) is too lazy to implement this "very rich" (ie: awful) API.  I've got my root in the picker, but I thought `queryChildren` should be called first.  However, `queryChildren is never called and it goes straight to`queryDocument`.

```
override fun queryRoots(projection: Array<out String>?): Cursor {
    // TODO: Likely need to be more strict about projection (ie: map to supported)
    val result = MatrixCursor(projection ?: DEFAULT_ROOT_PROJECTION)

    val row = result.newRow()
    row.add(DocumentsContract.Root.COLUMN_ROOT_ID, "com.anthonymandra.cloudprovider.dropbox")
    row.add(DocumentsContract.Root.COLUMN_ICON, R.drawable.ic_dropbox_gray)
    row.add(DocumentsContract.Root.COLUMN_TITLE, "Dropbox")
    row.add(DocumentsContract.Root.COLUMN_FLAGS, DocumentsContract.Root.FLAG_SUPPORTS_CREATE)   // TODO:
    row.add(DocumentsContract.Root.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID, ROOT_DOCUMENT_ID)
    return result
}

override fun queryChildDocuments(
    parentDocumentId: String?,
    projection: Array<out String>?,
    sortOrder: String?
): Cursor {
    // TODO: Likely need to be more strict about projection (ie: map to supported)
    val result = MatrixCursor(projection ?: DEFAULT_DOCUMENT_PROJECTION)
    val dropboxPath = if (parentDocumentId == ROOT_DOCUMENT_ID) "" else parentDocumentId

    try {
        val client = DropboxClientFactory.client

        var childFolders = client.files().listFolder(dropboxPath)
        while (true) {
            for (metadata in childFolders.entries) {
                addDocumentRow(result, metadata)
            }

            if (!childFolders.hasMore) {
                break
            }

            childFolders = client.files().listFolderContinue(childFolders.cursor)
        }
    } catch(e: IllegalStateException) { // Test if we can attempt auth thru the provider
        context?.let {
            Auth.startOAuth2Authentication(it, appKey)   // TODO: appKey
        }
    }
    return result
}

override fun queryDocument(documentId: String?, projection: Array<out String>?): Cursor {
    // TODO: Likely need to be more strict about projection (ie: map to supported)
    val result = MatrixCursor(projection ?: DEFAULT_DOCUMENT_PROJECTION)

    try {
        val client = DropboxClientFactory.client
        val metadata = client.files().getMetadata(documentId)
        addDocumentRow(result, metadata)
    } catch(e: IllegalStateException) { // Test if we can attempt auth thru the provider
        context?.let {
            Auth.startOAuth2Authentication(it, appKey)   // TODO: appKey
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: String 'path' does not match pattern
    at com.dropbox.core.v2.files.GetMetadataArg.<init>(GetMetadataArg.java:58)
    at com.dropbox.core.v2.files.GetMetadataArg.<init>(GetMetadataArg.java:80)
    at com.dropbox.core.v2.files.DbxUserFilesRequests.getMetadata(DbxUserFilesRequests.java:1285)
    at com.anthonymandra.cloudprovider.dropbox.DropboxProvider.queryDocument(DropboxProvider.kt:98)
    at android.provider.DocumentsProvider.query(DocumentsProvider.java:797)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:240)
    at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:102)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
```

`path` is `ROOT_DOCUMENT_ID` which I'm expecting to go to `queryChildDocuments` first.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why would you expect `queryChildDocuments()` to be either before or after `queryDocument()`? IOW, why are you making assumptions about the order of these calls?

Comment: When you first click on a root, I would expect the first call to be `queryChildDocuments`.  I thought the concept was that a root was assumed to be a  folder-type.  I'm still learning in motion here, but I expected `queryDocument` to kick in once something that was not `DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR` was clicked on.

Comment: I don't know if a root is required to be `MIME_TYPE_DIR`, and the only way clients can find out is via `queryDocument()`. In general, I would try to make very few assumptions about the order of these calls.

Comment: Gotcha, I already started placing the `""` dropbox root hack into the `queryDocument`.  I guess this makes sense in the end, just makes the init code seem more circular and a little uglier (with init hacks in both `queryDocument` and `queryChildDocuments`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for implementing a `DocumentsProvider` is... limited. In particular, there is no documented guarantee of the order of calls. As such, a `DocumentsProvider` really should be implemented to make as few assumptions as possible about the order of those calls.

For example, I would not assume that `queryRoots()` is called first. It probably will be first, if the first use of the `DocumentsProvider` for this process happens to be the Storage Access Framework UI. However, given that clients can (with care) persist a document or document tree `Uri`, you might wind up being called with something else first in your process, if the first thing happens to be a client using a persisted `Uri`.

And, in your specific case, I would not assume that `queryChildDocuments()` occurs before or after `queryDocument()`.

Comment: I hadn't even started thinking about persisted `Uri`, yet.  In my case, returning a pseudo folder in `queryDocument` for the `ROOT_DOCUMENT_ID` caused `queryChildDocuments` to be called.  Interestingly, I didn't end up with a `root` folder initially, it went ahead and populated the actual contents of the root (which was desired).

https://github.com/rcketscientist/CloudProvider

Answer (score 3):

I have also written a SAF DropBox implementation, and I also was a bit confused at first about this.

From the [documentation](http://www.androiddocs.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html):

Note the following:

- Each document provider reports one or more "roots" which are starting
  points into exploring a tree of documents. Each root has a unique
  COLUMN_ROOT_ID, and it points to a document (a directory)
  representing the contents under that root. Roots are dynamic by
  design to support use cases like multiple accounts, transient USB
  storage devices, or user login/log out.
- Under each root is a single document. That document points to 1 to N
  documents, each of which in turn can point to 1 to N documents.
- Each storage backend surfaces individual files and directories by
  referencing them with a unique COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID. Document IDs must
  be unique and not change once issued, since they are used for
  persistent URI grants across device reboots.
- Documents can be either an openable file (with a specific MIME type),
  or a directory containing additional documents (with the
  MIME_TYPE_DIR MIME type).
- Each document can have different capabilities, as described by
  COLUMN_FLAGS. For example,  FLAG_SUPPORTS_WRITE,
  FLAG_SUPPORTS_DELETE, and FLAG_SUPPORTS_THUMBNAIL. The same
  COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID can be included in multiple directories.

**That second bullet is the key bullet**. After the return from queryRoots(), for each root you passed back, the SAF makes a call to queryDocument(). This is essentially to create the "root file folder" document that appears in the list. What I did was in queryDocument() I check to see if the documentId passed in matches the unique value I gave to DocumentsContract.Root.COLUMN_ROOT_ID in the queryRoots() call. If it is, then you know this queryDocument() call needs to return a folder representing that root. Otherwise, I use the path from DropBox as my documentId everywhere else, so I use that documentID value in calls via DbxClientV2.

Here is some sample code - note that in my case I created an AbstractStorageProvider class from which all my various providers (Dropbox, Instagram, etc.) extend. The base class handles receiving the calls from SAF, and it does some housekeeping (like creating the cursors) and then calls the methods in the implementing classes to populate the cursors as required by that particular service:

Base Class

```
public Cursor queryRoots(final String[] projection) {
    Timber.d( "Lifecycle: queryRoots called");

    // If they are not paid up, they do not get to use any of these implementations
    if (!InTouchUtils.isLoginPaidSubscription()) {
        return null;
    }

    // Create a cursor with either the requested fields, or the default projection if "projection" is null.
    final MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(projection != null ? projection : getDefaultRootProjection());

    // Classes that extend this one must implement this method
    addRowsToQueryRootsCursor(cursor);

    return cursor;
}
```

From DropboxProvider addRowsToQueryRootsCursor:

```
protected void addRowsToQueryRootsCursor(MatrixCursor cursor) {
    // See if we need to init
    long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if ( !InTouchUtils.initDropboxClient()) {
        return;
    }
    Timber.d( "Time to test initialization of DropboxClient: %dms.", (System.currentTimeMillis() - l));
    l = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getApplicationContext());
        String displayname = sharedPrefs.getString(getContext().getString(R.string.pref_dropbox_displayname_token_key),
                getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.pref_dropbox_displayname_token_default));

        batchSize = Long.valueOf(Objects.requireNonNull(sharedPrefs.getString(getContext().getString(R.string.pref_dropbox_query_limit_key),
                getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.pref_dropbox_query_limit_key_default))));

        final MatrixCursor.RowBuilder row = cursor.newRow();

        row.add(DocumentsContract.Root.COLUMN_ROOT_ID, <YOUR_UNIQUE_ROOTS_KEY_HERE>);
        row.add(DocumentsContract.Root.COLUMN_TITLE,
                String.format(getContext().getString(R.string.dropbox_root_title),getContext().getString(R.string.app_name)));
        row.add(DocumentsContract.Root.COLUMN_SUMMARY,displayname+
                getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.dropbox_root_summary));
        row.add(DocumentsContract.Root.COLUMN_FLAGS, DocumentsContract.Root.FLAG_SUPPORTS_RECENTS | DocumentsContract.Root.FLAG_SUPPORTS_SEARCH);
        row.add(DocumentsContract.Root.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID,<YOUR_UNIQUE_ROOT_FOLDER_ID_HERE>);
        row.add(DocumentsContract.Root.COLUMN_ICON, R.drawable.intouch_for_dropbox);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Timber.d( "Called addRowsToQueryRootsCursor got exception, message was: %s", e.getMessage());
    }
    Timber.d( "Time to queryRoots(): %dms.", (System.currentTimeMillis() - l));
}
```

Then queryDocument() method in the base class:

```
@Override
public Cursor queryDocument(final String documentId, final String[] projection) {
    Timber.d( "Lifecycle: queryDocument called for: %s", documentId);

    // Create a cursor with either the requested fields, or the default projection if "projection" is null.
    // Return a cursor with a getExtras() method, to avoid the immutable ArrayMap problem.
    final MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(projection != null ? projection : getDefaultDocumentProjection()){
        Bundle cursorExtras = new Bundle();
        @Override
        public Bundle getExtras() {
            return cursorExtras;

        }
    };
    addRowToQueryDocumentCursor(cursor, documentId);
    return cursor;
}
```

And addRowToQueryDocumentCursor() in DropboxProvider:

```
protected void addRowToQueryDocumentCursor(MatrixCursor cursor,
                                           String documentId) {

    try {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getApplicationContext());
        String displayname = sharedPrefs.getString(getContext().getString(R.string.pref_dropbox_displayname_token_key),
                getContext().getString(R.string.pref_dropbox_displayname_token_default));
        if ( !InTouchUtils.initDropboxClient()) {
            return;
        }

        if ( documentId.equals(<YOUR_UNIQUE_ROOTS_ID_HERE>)) {
            // root Dir
            Timber.d( "addRowToQueryDocumentCursor called for the root");
            final MatrixCursor.RowBuilder row = cursor.newRow();
            row.add(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID, <YOUR_UNIQUE_FOLDER_ID_HERE>);
            row.add(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME,
                    String.format(getContext().getString(R.string.dropbox_root_title),
                                  getContext().getString(R.string.app_name)));
            row.add(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_SUMMARY,displayname+
                    getContext().getString(R.string.dropbox_root_summary));
            row.add(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_ICON, R.drawable.folder_icon_dropbox);
            row.add(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_MIME_TYPE, DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR);
            row.add(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_FLAGS, 0);
            row.add(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_SIZE, null);
            row.add(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED, null);
            return;
        }
        Timber.d( "addRowToQueryDocumentCursor called for documentId: %s", documentId);
        DbxClientV2 mDbxClient = DropboxClientFactory.getClient();
        Metadata metadata = mDbxClient.files().getMetadata(documentId);

        if ( metadata instanceof FolderMetadata) {
            Timber.d( "Document was a folder");
            includeFolder(cursor, (FolderMetadata)metadata);
        } else {
            Timber.d( "Document was a file");
            includeFile(cursor, (FileMetadata) metadata);
        }
    } catch (Exception e ) {
        Timber.d( "Called addRowToQueryDocumentCursor got exception, message was: %s documentId was: %s.", e.getMessage(), documentId);
    }
}
```